# Can IntelliJ create variables to fit a constructor signature?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, constructor

I know that <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> shows the signature and makes it easier to select what variables fit the best, but when no variable fits, is it possible to **create them automatically**?

e.g. I type `MyClass myObject = new MyClass(`

I would like IntelliJ to do help me creating variables to feed it:

```
// Generated variables
String name;
Integer value;

MyClass myObject = new MyClass(name, value);
```

Because for now, when I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> I see the signature:

[image]

And then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>, I can select existing variables, `null`, or create a new object by selecting `new`, but only an implementation:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can. Start out with typing your `new MyClass(name, value)`. Naturally, you'll get a compilation error (a squiggly red underline), since there's no appropriate constructor for these arguments. Place your caret over the error and press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>. When the context menu opens, select "create constructor", and just <kbd>ENTER</kbd> your way through its arguments.

Comment: Thank you, yes it's the way I do but when I have a big constructor, I don't want to type one by one all the variables, I would like IntelliJ to auto-complete, and/or offer me to create missing variables so that it becomes very quick to call my contructor.